# Como fazer para salvar a área de trabalho de projetos em Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ide

**Pergunta:** Gostaria de saber como eu devo proceder para salvar a área de trabalho do meu projeto, que seria, os `.pas` que estavam abertas quando eu estava trabalhando antes de fecha-lo, e ao re-abrir o Delphi, eu teria todos estes arquivos abertos como eu dexei antes de sair. (ou antes de o programa travar, fechar sozinho).

É possível fazer isto?

Caso for, gostaria de saber como.

Comment: Qual a sua pergunta exatamente?

Comment: Também fiquei perdido quanto à pergunta. E se você achou uma resposta, não edite a pergunta, responda-a você mesmo.

Comment: Eu tentei responder, mas o site nao deixou pedindo para responder em 8 horas... Depois do tempo vou postar entao

Comment: Aproveite dê uma melhorada na pergunta para que ela possa ser reaberta.

Comment: @User, estamos a tentar reabrir a pergunta. Assim você pode responder, e completar a pergunta, para outros na comunidade tambem poderem aprender com o seu problema!

Comment: @PauloRoberto Pergunta reaberta, se quiser adicionar a resposta.

Comment: Opa, vim aqui editar mas ja arrumaram, correria sabe como é... Obrigado a todos!

Comment: @User, hei User, que se a pergunta te ajudou, que tal marcar ela como a mais correta? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

use o menu `Tools` -> `Options` e marque as duas opções de `Autosave options` em `Environment Options`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]